# Missing required parameters for [Route: get:manage_products] [URI: admin/manage-products/{id}]?

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, laravel-5.5

when I pass data in URL in Laravel 5.5 comes below error.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: get:manage_products] [URI:
>   admin/manage-products/{id}]. (View:
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxx/resources/views/admin/layout/include/sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/resources/views/admin/layout/include/sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxx/resources/views/admin/layout/include/sidebar.blade.php)

My code looks like below mention

web.php

```
Route::get('manage-products/{id}', ['as' => 'get:manage_products', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getManageProducts']);
```

select_store.blade.php

```
<p><a href="{{ route('get:manage_products', $store->id) }}">Go To Store</a></p>
```

admincontroller.php

```
public function getManageProducts($id)
    {
   //
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Are you using subdomain ? what is your url format ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error using your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `route('get:manage_products', ['id' => $store->id])`

Comment: could it be that instead of `$store->id` you should have `$product->id`?

Comment: i define $store not a $product. i want to do.. first select store from select_store.blade.php then show all product related store in manage_products.blade.php

Comment: Can you try to dump `$store` in blade just to check if the `id` attribute exists and is not null? and/or the html it outputs

Comment: $store->id is print 1

Comment: And does the output of the html match `<p><a href="/manage-products/1">Go To Store</a></p>`?

Comment: <p><a href="/manage-products?1">Go To Store</a></p> its look like this ....

Comment: No clue i'm afraid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170361/discussion-between-bizz-website-and-quezler).